# In mySQL 5.6, whats the default behavior of the ALGORITHM parameter?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.6 (and its Online-DDL feature) to generate some in-place alter table operations like "ADD COLUMN." I see that the LOCK parameter defaults to the highest level of concurrency allowed (for ADD COLUMN this should be "NONE") but what is the default behavior for the ALGORITHM parameter? In the documentation it says "ALGORITHM = DEFAULT is the same a specifying no ALGORITHM clause at all." but that's not helpful because it doesn't say what ALGORITHM = DEFAULT is equal to.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default depends on what kind of change you're trying to apply.

Some changes can make use of ALGORITHM=INPLACE, so this is their default. Other changes can never use online DDL, so their default is ALGORITHM=COPY. For example, changing a data type or dropping a primary key cannot be done inplace.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html. They document how different operations are handled, and the ones that say "No" in the "Inplace" column use ALGORITHM=COPY by default, and fail if you try to use ALGORITHM=INPLACE.

You can force an operation to use ALGORITHM=COPY even if it could do its work inplace, but you cannot request a operation to use ALGORITHM=INPLACE if it can't do it.

Comment: Ok, so its similar to the default of the "lock" parameter where MySQL tries to allow as much concurrency as possible. Thanks! I think you helped me a few weeks ago as well when I was asking about percona. Definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! Remember to reciprocate by upvoting, or marking as accepted answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: So I just tried an "ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN... " statement and it took 3 minutes on a a table with 5 million rows. The table appeared locked during this operation. However when I reran the statement and appended ",ALGORITHM=inplace, LOCK=none" then it took 6 minutes, but the table remained available to be used. I thought those were the defaults so why did I have to specify them explicitly?